# My loop is supposed to return an average after a certain value is entered, but I cannot break out of the loop

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner with javascript in my first class. I've spent the last few hours working on a homework problem:

"Code a web page to calculate average test scores entered by the user. User should enter 999 to indicate that they are done entering test scores. At this time the page should display the average of the entered scores."

I have the window prompt doing what I want it to do as far as entries go; however, whenever it comes to entering 999, the loop does not stop running and does not calculate the average.

I tried entering break statements at various parts of the code, most of which were illegal.

I've tried various logical operators.

I've searched around but a lot of the potential answers are in coding languages I do not know.

```
// declare variables
var score = [];
var average = (total / score.length);
var total = 0;

// run the loop
while (score !== 999) {
    score.push(prompt("Please input a test score\nIf you are done, please 
enter 999 to get the average."));
    }   for (var i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        total += score[i];
        } if (score === 999 ) { // display alert message
            alert("The average of those scores is: " + average);
        }
```

The window prompt is supposed to take any amount of numbers and put them into an array. Once 999 is entered, the prompt displays the average of all numbers that were previously entered into the array.

Comment: It looks like your `score` variable is an array and not an integer. You are pushing answers from the prompt into this array. So this condition `score === 999` will never be true.

Comment: Instead of pushing `prompt()` into the array, store it in a variable first. Then use something like `if (input == 999) break;`

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to use the browser console and debugger.  That will let you step thru your code and see for yourself what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
var score = [];
```

score is declared as an array.

Then values are pushed into the array.

```
while (score !== 999)
```

`score` is never equal to `999`, since it is an array. You can instead compare an element of the array by indexing to it (e.g. `score[0]`).

Index instead to the last element of the array (the latest one, just pushed into it)

```
while (score[score.length-1] !== 999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the last element in the array is `999`:

```
while (!score[--score.length] != 999)
```

However, for this to work, you need to use `parseInt` on your `prompt`:

```
score.push(parseInt(prompt("Please input a test score\nIf you are done, please enter 999 to get the average.")));
```